# Get response from UrlFetchApp.Fetch() in Google app script and print on Logger

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, element

I wanted to get the HTML elements using UrlFetchApp.Fetch on this URL,using following code. However, it seems that only certain URLs work. Other URLs just returns 500 or a Bad request.

```
   function getHTML()
    {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.theoutlet24.com/th/catalogsearch/\
                                       result/index/?cat=0&limit=all&q=4X4Man");
      Logger.log(response);
    }
```

Any help in this matter is appreciable .

Comment: are you Using App script?

Answer (score 5):

Add just `{muteHttpExceptions:true}` as an option after URL.I have tested its working!

```
    function getHTML()
    {
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.theoutlet24.com/th/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=0&limit=all&q=4X4Man",{muteHttpExceptions:true});
     Logger.log(response);
    }
```